# How to format a document so it compiles with tex.exe?

Tags: xetex, pdftex, luatex

I have a distribution of TeX installed, which does not include LaTeX.  So compiling even trivial examples of documents gives "Undefined control sequence" errors even for something like `\documentclass` and `\usepackage`.  I tried searching online, but everything that calls itself "TeX" seems to actually be LaTeX.  Can someone provide an example of something non-trivial that would compile with TeX.exe (or PDFTeX, XeTeX, LuaTeX)? -- so I can get started trying to format my documents to compile?  For example, a math fraction... anything.

Update: Apparently there is a texi2pdf script included.  It works in CygWin (modulo citations not being there, even after I call BibTeX on my file) -- is there a way to have a similar script work in Windows?  Entering CygWin takes about 60 seconds each time...

Comment: Exactly what have you installed? Learning to write in plain tex would probably be a much bigger pain than installing a system that includes latex compilers.

Comment: Did you try to compile your document with pdflatex? It would be very unusual if this weren't there.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Nope, `pdflatex` is definitely not there.  As is anything including the `la`.

Comment: @daleif This is a distribution that comes with CygWin, and includes the files listed in my post -- PDFTex, XeTeX, LuaTex, Tex, etc.

Comment: the cygwin texlive includes latex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I did a search, and I don't see it anywhere... do you know how I can find it?

Comment: pdflatex will be  a symbolic link to tex, if that is not there as you have deleted it somewhere go to the cygwin setup and re-install tex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ... but TeX doesn't compile my file, as indicated in the above post.  So pdflatex cannot be a symbolic link...  I didn't delete it, I just installed it today.

Comment: you need to use pdflatex not tex if it has latex syntax

Comment: if for some reason the latex format is not there run `fmtutil-sys --all` to remake the formats

Answer (score 1):

The cygwin distribution includes latex, on your system look in `/usr/bin` it should look like

```
$ pwd
/usr/bin

$ ls -l *tex
-rwxr-xr-x 1 nm grfp 394 Sep  1  2018 dot2tex
lrwxrwxrwx 1 nm grfp  10 Jun 18 10:10 dvilualatex -> luatex.exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 nm grfp  10 Jun 18 10:09 dviluatex -> luatex.exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 nm grfp  10 Jun 18 10:09 etex -> pdftex.exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 nm grfp   7 Jun 18 10:09 initex -> tex.exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 nm grfp  10 Jun 18 10:10 latex -> pdftex.exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 nm grfp  12 Jun 18 10:10 lualatex -> luahbtex.exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 nm grfp  10 Jun 18 10:09 pdfetex -> pdftex.exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 nm grfp  10 Jun 18 10:10 pdflatex -> pdftex.exe
lrwxrwxrwx 1 nm grfp  49 Jun 18 10:09 simpdftex -> /usr/share/texmf-dist/scripts/simpdftex/simpdftex
```

Comment: I was looking for something that I can run in Windows, without having to enter Cygwin to compile my files.  And nothing including LaTeX is available in Windows.

Comment: the cygwin tex will not work that way. Install a windows tex for that. @Alex

Comment: I see. But the cygwin tex *is* compiling simple TeX files -- i.e., no math, no packages, e.g. formatted text.  Is there no simple way to change my files to have it recognize them as well?

Comment: I'd like to know from where you have that nothing including LaTeX is available in Windows? Because then I have many colleagues that who'd beg to differ.

Comment: @Alex you can not see the symbolic links in windows, but even the executables that you can see will not work unless the cygwin shared libraries and the texlive utility programs are in your path which will not typically be the case. Some very simple cases may seem to work but it is tricky and completely unsupported and has very restricted functionality to use it in that way.

Comment: @daleif I guess I should have said "in my setup".  I know it is possible, but I don't have it installed right now.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I believe the way Cygwin installed it, all the programs and libraries got dumped in the same directory.  So I guess that's why it is compiling files right now.  The issue is, at my University I have the exact same setup, except I cannot enter cygwin there.  So I need to figure out how much I can accomplish once I am back at my University.

Comment: +1 for suggestion to run `fmtutil-sys --all` -- I remember this was necessary at one point.

Comment: @Alex it is a suggestion for general use but it will not help you run cygwin tex from windows. Nothing will help that: you are asking to do something unsupported.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see.  Wonder why they made TeX.exe executable in Windows then... What makes me wonder even more is, why my University set that TeX.exe as their default `.tex` file compiler...

Comment: @Alex your description of the university setup seems (to put it mildly) strange. If you can install a cygwin tex why can you not switch to cygwin? Conversely if you can not switch to cygwin why can you not install a windows tex?

Comment: @Alex that is how cygwin works all cygwin programs are windows .exe exceutables.  A windows tex would also be` tex.exe` but compiled to work in windows.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What the setup is, that the CygWin TeX.exe is installed, and set as the default .tex file compiler.  BUT -- the University bought only so many licenses for CygWin, and there is a line of people who want to enter it.  So typically I mark that I would like to enter CygWin, and the University keeps track of how many students are using it right now, and when a slot frees up (typically 20-45 minutes), then they download it to the computer and allow me to enter it.  Really, more of a software licensing issue.

Comment: you don't need licences for cygwin it's free and open source. Anyone can download it from the cygwin site. @Alex

Comment: @Alex why don't you simply use overleaf that gives you a full tex system accessible online and no need for a local install at all.

Comment: Maybe I'll bring this up to the system administrator then.  Because right now CygWin is managed using the exact same license management software as Photoshop, Office 365, AutoCAD, etc.  Which I know that much software is free but for personal users; to corporations it requires buying licenses -- I was assuming CygWin was the same way.

Comment: Regarding Overleaf -- I typically edit my TeX files offline; using OverLeaf would require cutting and pasting every time I want to compile it, and then saving the file back onto my USB so I can take it to the printer.  A local install only requires a single command to compile and save onto the USB.

Comment: @Alex  well you need to a local install that matches your operating system

Comment: the tex.exe you see is in `\cygwin64\bin` ? If so does that have other programs such as bash and mintty?  if it does then most likely `\cygwin64\bin\mintty -` will open a command window set up for cygwin and pdflatex will work